# Difference between "android.permission" and "ANDROID.PERMISSION" when use uses-permission in manifest

Tags: android-manifest, android-permissions

When declare uses-permission, i meet both of them:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I tried to create a folder in SDCard with each of those permission, it's success.
This is my demo code:

```
 private void initFolders() {
        File rootFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Constants.ROOT_FOLDER_NAME);
        if (!rootFolder.isDirectory()){
            boolean success = rootFolder.mkdirs();
            if (!success){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't create root folder!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, could someone tell me what is the main difference between them?

Comment: I seen this is happening when you select something from Android Studio Dropdown help.

Comment: Yes, and I want to know what is the difference, and why didn't Android Studio show the same in lower case?

Comment: I feel like a mistake only. But not sure.